# Better way of getting index from multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am using following code to create an array to find out start and end index of a multidimensional array:

```
var valueArray = Enumerable.Range(0, val.GetLength(1))
                                     .Where(index => val[0, index].Contains("Rak"))
                                     .ToArray();
```

Than i am using valueArray to get start index which is valueArray[0] and end index which will be valueArray[valueArray.Length-1].

Above code works. But it looks like it is doing aweful amout of work to get start and end index. As it is first creating valueArray putting in all values in it and then getting index values. Can anyone suggest better way of doing this?

Defination of array:

```
private string[,] _val;
 public string[,] val
        {
            [Pure]
            get
            {
                if (_val != null)
                    return (string[,])_val.Clone();
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                _val = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your implementation.  Is speed/efficiency that much of a factor for what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Brian - Yes speed is an issue if i have to go through array of lets say 6k rows its taking very long time.

Comment: I would think another strategy, can't you create an index? Or a List of Lists?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - create an index? That is what i am doing right? Any other way?

Comment: What does the array contains? [int,string]? I would define it like `Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>` This way you can call directly val[i].Contains("Rak");

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - No [string,string]

Comment: Can you show the definition and some example you store in?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - Added the defination.

Comment: Ok, but what is the goal of this, it need to find strings? I don't get any imagination what it should do. You're scanning the array of strings? is it a puzzle? I bbl

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - Its basically need to show these results on an excel file. So all Rok values should show up on one comlumn. Than i pass in another value lets say Sac it should show on next column and so on.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - In above code can i put all values in list some how? Rather than using an array? That will help me? If i can how can that be done?

Comment: @NoviceMe creating a one-dimentional array from multidimensional is longer, than to search inside multidimensional array.

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly - Can all values be put in a list rather than array somehow?

Comment: List contains an array inside

Comment: So not every cell contains rak/sac? Can't you store an struct with `{ Row, Col, Value }` in one list? This will speed-up searching and saves memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to optimize the code is to search first and last elements from the begining and from the end respectively.

```
int firstIndex;
int lastIndex; 
for(int i = 0; i < val.GetLength(1); i++)
{
    if(val[0,i].Contains("Rak"))
    {
        firstIndex = i;
        break;
    } 
}
for(int i = val.GetLength(1) - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if(val[0,i].Contains("Rak"))
    {
        lastIndex = i;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather would go for something like this:

```
public class CellInfo
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
List<CellInfo> _cells = new List<CellInfo>();

public void Example()
{
    _cells.Add(new CellInfo { Column = 6, Row = 3, Value = "Rak" });
    _cells.Add(new CellInfo { Column = 3, Row = 8, Value = "Rak" });
    _cells.Add(new CellInfo { Column = 2, Row = 4, Value = "Rak" });
    _cells.Add(new CellInfo { Column = 5, Row = 7, Value = "Sac" });
    _cells.Add(new CellInfo { Column = 1, Row = 3, Value = "Sac" });
```

---

```
    int[] rowRakAtColumn0 = _cells.Where(cell => cell.Column == 0
                                        && cell.Value.Contains("Rak"))
                                            .OrderBy(cell => cell.Row)
                                                .Select(cell => cell.Row)
                                                    .ToArray();

    CellInfo[] row0Values = _cells.Where(cell => cell.Row == 0)
                                .OrderBy(cell => cell.Column)
                                    .ToArray();
}
```

---

Converting it to a multi array (if needed)

```
public string[,] ToMultiArray(List<CellOffset> cells)
{
    string[,] multiDimentional = new string[
        cells.Max(cell => cell.Column), cells.Max(cell => cell.Row)];

    cells.ForEach(cell => 
        multiDimentional[cell.Column, cell.Row] = cell.Value);

    return multiDimentional;
}

string[,] values = ToMultiArray(_cells);
```

---

**Answer to lazzy_ms:**

The linq `.Select()` method is also able to pass the index as second parameter for your lambda function. You only need to capture it in an anonymous class.

```
var result = _cells
    //             here         and capture it in an object
    //              |
    .Select((Item, Index) => new { Item, Index })
    .FirstOrDefault(itemWithIndex => itemWithIndex.Item.Column == 5);

Console.WriteLine($"The index of column 5 is {result?.Index}");
```

Make sure you select the index before any filtering takes place. else it wont match

Comment: Hey, I made a class for data, same way. I just want the index of an item containing `name = "customer1"`.

Comment: @lazzy_ms you mean the  Column and Row?

Comment: Yes, in this example, I want the index of `column = 5`. That would be `3`